# setting image as background is not working

Tags: codenameone

It is a simple problem but i have no idea why it is not working. Previously I did same and it always worked but now it is not working whatever I do. I set bgImage but it somehow doesn't work. If I set image named "group" as Button munuIcon1 = new Button(group) it works. But the following gives blank form

```
    Image group = theme.getImage("group.png").scaledWidth(imgWidth / 3 - 10);
    Button menuIcon1 = new Button();
    menuIcon1.setUIID("menuButtonzz");
    menuIcon1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));
    menuIcon1.getUnselectedStyle().setBgImage(group);//tried getAllStyles() too

    //tried couple of things but doesn't work
    menuIcon1.getAllStyles().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED);
    menuIcon1.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);//tried value to 0 as well
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest using [ScaledImageButton](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/ScaleImageButton.html) which is effectively what you are trying to implement.

[Button](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Button.html) derives from `Label` which has a special case for hiding blank labels & in this case the `Button` is effectively blank.

There are two ways to workaround this, the old way was creating `new Button(" ")`. This makes the `Button` seem non-blank and thus it's renderered.

The newer way is to use [setShowEvenIfBlank(true)](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Label.html#setShowEvenIfBlank-boolean-).